# Retornar todos os resultados em uma consulta agrupada mesmo se a soma for zero ou nula

Tags: sql, query, oracle11g, oracle11c

Tenho a seguinte consulta agrupada:

```
SELECT 

SUM(SUC.PESO),
EXTRACT(DAY FROM HU.FIM),

CASE WHEN (ACO.COLUNA_2 IN ('L','C') AND HU.ESP_MM_UNMET<=3) THEN 'Carb' WHEN (ACO.COLUNA_2 IN ('L','C') 
AND HU.ESP_MM_UNMET>3) THEN 'Carb' WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,3)='P39') THEN 'Duplex' WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P3') THEN '3XX' 

WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P2') THEN '3XX' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P4') THEN '4XX' 
WHEN (ACO.COD_IDENT_FMACO='GNO') THEN 'GNO' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,4)='P999') THEN 'GO' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,4)='P989') THEN 'GO' ELSE 'XXX' END TIPO_PRODUTO



FROM 
PROCESSO_HIST HU, 
PROCESSO_HIST HU1, 
ACO, 
SUCATAS SUC, 
CODIGOS COD 
WHERE 
HU.COD_IDENT_ACO = ACO.COD_IDENT_ACO AND 
HU.COD_IDENT_PRODC= SUC.COD_IDENT_PRODCAND 
HU.SEQ_OPERA_PRODC= SUC.SEQ_OPERA_PRODCAND 
HU1.COD_IDENT_PRODC= HU.COD_IDENT_PRODCAND 
HU1.SEQ_OPERA_PRODC= (HU.SEQ_OPERA_PRODC-1) AND 
SUC.COD_IDENT_GERAL = COD.COD_IDENT_GERAL(+) AND  
COD.CODIGO_TYPE(+) = 'MOTSUCLTQ' AND  
SUC.CODIGO_TYPE = 'MOTSUCA' AND 
HU.COD_EQPMT_PRODC IN ('LDP', 'LTQ', 'BTQ', 'DBQ', 'TL8') AND 
NOT EXISTS 
( 
SELECT '1' 
FROM 
PROCESSO_HIST HU2, 
ACO A 
WHERE 
A.COD_IDENT_ACO = HU2.COD_IDENT_ACO AND 
HU2.COD_IDENT_PRODC= HU.COD_IDENT_PRODCAND 
HU2.SEQ_OPERA_PRODC= HU.SEQ_OPERA_PRODCAND 
HU2.COD_EQPMT_PRODC = 'EMB' AND 
(A.COD_IDENT_ACO NOT LIKE 'L%' AND A.COD_IDENT_ACO NOT LIKE 'C%') 
) 
AND 
HU.COD_EQPMT_PRODC_DEPOSITO <> 'SUC' AND 
HU.FIM >= TO_DATE('01052019000000', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS') AND 
HU.FIM <= TO_DATE('31052019235959', 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS')
GROUP BY
EXTRACT(DAY FROM HU.FIM),
CASE WHEN (ACO.COLUNA_2 IN ('L','C') AND HU.ESP_MM_UNMET<=3) THEN 'Carb' WHEN (ACO.COLUNA_2 IN ('L','C') 
AND HU.ESP_MM_UNMET>3) THEN 'Carb' WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,3)='P39') THEN 'Duplex' WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P3') THEN '3XX' 

WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P2') THEN '3XX' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P4') THEN '4XX' 
WHEN (ACO.COD_IDENT_FMACO='GNO') THEN 'GNO' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,4)='P999') THEN 'GO' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,4)='P989') THEN 'GO' ELSE 'XXX' END

ORDER BY
EXTRACT(DAY FROM HU.FIM),
CASE WHEN (ACO.COLUNA_2 IN ('L','C') AND HU.ESP_MM_UNMET<=3) THEN 'Carb' WHEN (ACO.COLUNA_2 IN ('L','C') 
AND HU.ESP_MM_UNMET>3) THEN 'Carb' WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,3)='P39') THEN 'Duplex' WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P3') THEN '3XX' 

WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P2') THEN '3XX' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,2)='P4') THEN '4XX' 
WHEN (ACO.COD_IDENT_FMACO='GNO') THEN 'GNO' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,4)='P999') THEN 'GO' 
WHEN (SUBSTR(ACO.COLUNA_1,1,4)='P989') THEN 'GO' ELSE 'XXX' END
```

Essa consulta me retorna a soma de um campo do banco de dados com a seguinte estrutura:

1º -> Soma do peso
2º -> Dia da soma
3º -> Grupo de Tipo de Produto.

O problema é que eu não tenho todos os produtos em todos os dias e então atualmente se eu tive a produção de dois produtos no dia 1º ela me retorna o seguinte resultado;

Peso  Dia Produto

10000 1   3XX

56000 1   4XX

Só que eu preciso que a consulta sempre retorne todos os tipos de produto, mesmo se no dia ele não tiver tido produção, por exemplo no dia primeiro ele deveria me retornar:

Peso  Dia Produto

10000 1 3XX

56000 1 4XX

0 1 Carb

0 1 Duplex

0 1 GNO

0 1 GO

Comment: Olá! Veja se consegue o resultado que você precisa usando o left join na tabela do que traz o produto, além disso você precisará tratar os campos que porventura ficarem nulos.

Comment: Uma ideia básica e gerar valores "zerados" e agregar https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/522521-for%C3%A7ar-select-trazer-linha-mesmo-que-sem-valor/?tab=comments#comment-2079599   https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/543061-query-com-contador-a-partir-de-um-mes/?do=findComment&comment=2169834